# Firebase cloud function timestamp

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my current application, I store a value in Firestore for each user something along the lines of this:
User1Doc - hasUsedFeatureToday = true
User2Doc - hasUsedFeatureToday = false
...

At the end of the day, I run a scheduled function that resets all of these to false. This was fine while my application was relatively small, but does not scale very effectively as I'm sure you can imagine.

Each user can only use this aspect of my app once per day, so the only time this field is read is when they try to use it.

I would like to change this system to store a timestamp in the user's document when they use the feature and then check if this timestamp is the same day (Europe/London time) if someone tries to use it again.

Does Firebase offer a way to get a "timezoned" timestamp like this and store/check it with the Firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store a timestamp (UTC). Whenever users logs in to your app, just check the timestamp and update the same. You can always use libraries like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) to get local time from the UTC time.

If you want to allow the user to update this timestamp only once, you can use [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) to restrict the same. However, user may try to prevent the timestamp from being updated at first place.

You can instead use Cloud Function to serve the data only when the user requests it. This will be better than updating documents of all users even if they won't be using the feature every day.

Comment: I think I see, so I can just use the DateTime.now().setZone("Europe/London") and store that in my database, then just check that as and when I need to? Thanks!

Comment: @0x6f6b no, when you store date in a database, it's usually UTC. But you can convert it to  your timezone  before running your logic. What you are trying to restrict once per day to user here 
?

Comment: It's a raffle-like feature that each user can only enter once to prevent people from increasing their chances of winning. The timezone checks I want to keep on the server side because I want people to be able to enter once every day (London time) no matter where they are in the world and be able to enter again at the beginning of each "London day". Does my initial comment seem like it would work for this? I wouln't mind switching to UTC, when you mention using UTC time, how do I get that timestamp, Date.now()?

Comment: @0x6f6b this is doable but it might be best to use a Cloud Function to ensure that their status is updated. You can check when was their "hasUsedToday" updated but the problem here is users can prevent the application from updating this value in Firestore. But if you get the value through a CF (at least once a day), you can check this securely on server side.

Comment: This works quite well for my application, because the only way someone can join the raffle is through a "joinGame" CF, so I could just embed this check into there. The main reason I want to do this is to reduce the crazy amount of writes that my current method does each night.

Comment: @0x6f6b yes, if you want to reduce CF usage, maybe you can cache the status locally for some time. It's better to do these calculations only when user requests some data instead of for all users every day.

Comment: Definitely, thanks for the help!